# laravel best way to automatically load a head/footer to a view (without blade)

Tags: php, laravel

is there any way a template header and footer file can be loaded to a view without having to call a controller or have to call it in every controller?

```
views/includes/header.php
views/includes/footer.php
```

I'm not using blade templating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that most (if not all) of Laravel's Classes are available everywhere due to it's dependency injection. You can use the View::make() method in views, not just controllers. So you can do this in your  main view:

```
<?php echo View::make('includes/header'); ?>

    <?php echo $content; ?>

<?php echo View::make('includes/footer'); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use blade templates e.g.:

### views/home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts/master')

@section('content')
    <p>Put your views code in here</p>
@stop
```

### views/layouts/master.blade.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header></header>
@yeild('content')
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately we're not using blade, is there a way it can be done without?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd advise you try to use blade, as it will work with standard php <?php echo 'stuff' ?> and also with the blade syntax. This will give you the ability to share code with partials as well via @include('view/name')

Comment: actually i decided to do this since it's just the structure that uses blade it's not too bothersome. best solution i think